# How can I filter the new lists elements?

Tags: javascript

Sorry for the long code but I have been trying to find the problem since last night. The goals are:

- When a user enters any lists value it creates a new list containing that  value.
- When the user clicks the delete button of the specified lists it will be removed.
- When the user enters any value in the search bar, if any lists value is equivalent to the search input it should be showed.
- The problem is that when I enter into the search bar a list value it doesn't display anything

  ```js
  const btn = document.querySelector("input[type=submit]");
  const ulTag = document.querySelector("ul");
  const form = document.querySelector("form");
  const search = document.querySelectorAll("input")[0];

  form.addEventListener("submit", createElement);
  search.addEventListener("keyup", filterItems);
  function createElement(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const input = document.querySelectorAll("input")[1];
    const lists = document.createElement("li");
    const removebtn = document.createElement("button");
    removebtn.className = "btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right delete";
    lists.className = "li";
    removebtn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("X"));
    const listsValue = document.createTextNode(input.value);
    lists.appendChild(removebtn);
    lists.appendChild(listsValue);
    ulTag.appendChild(lists);
    if (input.value === "") {
      form.removeEventListener("submit", createElement);
    }
  }


  function filterItems(e) {
    const searchInput = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
    let allItems = ulTag.getElementsByTagName("li");
    Array.from(allItems).forEach(list => {
      let itemNames = list.firstChild.textContent;
      if (itemNames.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchInput) != -1) {
        list.style.display = "block";
      } else if (itemNames.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchInput) == -1) {
        list.style.display = "none";
      }
    });
  }
  ```

Comment: So what's the question? What's the problem you're having?

Comment: Please read this, and update your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What you are trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 0):

One problem :
Ans: itemNames should be equal to list.lastChild.textContent;